# NEO4J merge list of objects and relate to other node

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a list of phones numbers and I want to merge all the list into my NEO4J and create unique relationship if not exists

```
List<ContactPhoneNumber> phones = new List<ContactPhoneNumber>();

WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
               .Unwind(phones, "node")
               .CreateUnique("(isuser:BaseUser{guid: '" + userid + "'})-[:PHONES_FROM_DEVICE]->(isphone:ContactPhoneNumber)")
               .Set("isphone = node")
               .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

the error i got is

> PatternException: Unbound pattern!

and the stack trace from NEO4J

> at
>   Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteCypher(CypherQuery
>   query) in D:\temp\c4dadf9\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 1075 \n 
>   at Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherFluentQuery.ExecuteWithoutResults() in
>   D:\temp\c4dadf9\Neo4jClient\Cypher\CypherFluentQuery.cs:line 429

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE UNIQUE` requires that at least one of the nodes in the pattern be "bound" to an existing node.

This statement might work for you:

```
WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(phones, "node")
    .Merge("(isuser:BaseUser{ guid: {userid} })")
    .CreateUnique("(isuser)-[:PHONES_FROM_DEVICE]->(isphone:ContactPhoneNumber {isPhone: node})")
    .WithParam("userid", userid)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

It:

- Uses `MERGE` to get (or create if non-existent) the desired `BaseUser` node, `isuser`.
- Uses a `CREATE UNIQUE` pattern that is "bound" to `isuser`.
- Eliminates the `SET` clause, and assigns the `isPhone` property inside the `CREATE UNIQUE` clause, since that would properly prevent duplicates.
- Passes the `userid` value as a parameter (which is more secure and performant).

Comment: your code was big help i think I was solve my issue 
I use this code
            WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
                .Unwind(phones, "node")
                .Merge("(isuser:BaseUser{ guid: '"+userid+"'})")
                .Merge("(isphone:ContactPhoneNumber{phone: node.phone } )")
                .CreateUnique("(isuser)-[:PHONES_FROM_DEVICE]->(isphone)")
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
I add merge to contactphonenumber node , maybe becuase phone has constrains!